# When iPhone is locked we can't approve or deny notification from apple watch

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, apple-push-notifications, visual-studio-2019

I can't approve or deny notification from apple watch in my Xamarin app, it's happened only when the iPhone is locked. This case was not working after updating to xamarin.ios SDK 13 everything is working fine before the update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution that Someone was turn ON the Data Protection mode in developer account and I notice that mode is disabled in previous provisioning profile so again I turn OFF the Data Protection mode and create a new provisioning profile and make a new build then Approve and Deny button functionality works fine. Data Protection mode blocks the access of local files when it turn ON. This bug is not related to xamarin.ios SDK 13.